# Old school stranded on an island movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to remember an old movie I remember watching with my parents.

A group of people are stranded on an island somehow they end up making shelter and start exploring. They end up finding booby traps and the father of one falls into one and gets injured or dies, can't remember which. Now one of the girls ends up finding a cave, it has old Japanese-like stuff in there books etc. and an old sword (katana) and she starts studying all the journals of the owner who obviously was stranded and died there too.

That's all I remember, does anyone know what this is?

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and [edit] in anymore details you may remember? For example, you say it was an old movie, when did you see it? Was it older than when you saw it? etc.

Comment: How is this SF or Fantasy related?

Comment: Hi. From your description, I can't see a sci-fi or fantasy element to your movie. Could you add to it or perhaps post on the movies stack exchange.

Comment: Movies SE doesn't do identifications anymore. Tvtropes's YKTS is probably their best bet.